# Why does the Snakemake GSRemoteProvider `stay_on_remote=True` argument cause different behavior across Windows and Linux?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, snakemake

I have the following Snakefile (using Snakemake v7.6.0):

```
from snakemake.remote.GS import RemoteProvider as GSRemoteProvider
GS = GSRemoteProvider(project="my-gcp-project-id")

rule example2:
  output: 
    GS.remote('my-gcs-bucket/path/to/test.txt', stay_on_remote=True)

  shell: 'touch test.txt && gsutil mv test.txt gs://my-gcs-bucket/path/to/test.txt'
```

When I run this in Linux (using WSL2), the job completes successfully -- the file is uploaded to GCS, and Snakemake reports that it finished the job:

```
...

Finished job 0.
1 of 1 steps (100%) done
```

However, when I run the same rule in Windows (using GitBash), I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\my-user-name\Miniconda3\envs\my-miniconda-env-name\lib\site-packages\snakemake\__init__.py", line 722, in snakemake
    success = workflow.execute(
  File "C:\Users\my-user-name\Miniconda3\envs\my-miniconda-env-name\lib\site-packages\snakemake\workflow.py", line 1110, in execute
    success = self.scheduler.schedule()
  File "C:\Users\my-user-name\Miniconda3\envs\my-miniconda-env-name\lib\site-packages\snakemake\scheduler.py", line 510, in schedule
    self.run(runjobs)
  File "C:\Users\my-user-name\Miniconda3\envs\my-miniconda-env-name\lib\site-packages\snakemake\scheduler.py", line 558, in run
    executor.run_jobs(
  File "C:\Users\my-user-name\Miniconda3\envs\my-miniconda-env-name\lib\site-packages\snakemake\executors\__init__.py", line 120, in run_jobs
    self.run(
  File "C:\Users\my-user-name\Miniconda3\envs\my-miniconda-env-name\lib\site-packages\snakemake\executors\__init__.py", line 486, in run
    future = self.run_single_job(job)
  File "C:\Users\my-user-name\Miniconda3\envs\my-miniconda-env-name\lib\site-packages\snakemake\executors\__init__.py", line 539, in run_single_job
    self.cached_or_run, job, run_wrapper, *self.job_args_and_prepare(job)
  File "C:\Users\my-user-name\Miniconda3\envs\my-miniconda-env-name\lib\site-packages\snakemake\executors\__init__.py", line 491, in job_args_and_prepare
    job.prepare()
  File "C:\Users\my-user-name\Miniconda3\envs\my-miniconda-env-name\lib\site-packages\snakemake\jobs.py", line 770, in prepare
    f.prepare()
  File "C:\Users\my-user-name\Miniconda3\envs\my-miniconda-env-name\lib\site-packages\snakemake\io.py", line 618, in prepare
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\my-user-name\Miniconda3\envs\my-miniconda-env-name\lib\site-packages\snakemake\io.py", line 614, in prepare
    os.makedirs(dir, exist_ok=True)
  File "C:\Users\my-user-name\Miniconda3\envs\my-miniconda-env-name\lib\os.py", line 213, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
  File "C:\Users\my-user-name\Miniconda3\envs\my-miniconda-env-name\lib\os.py", line 213, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
  File "C:\Users\my-user-name\Miniconda3\envs\my-miniconda-env-name\lib\os.py", line 223, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)

  FileNotFoundError: [WinError 161] The specified path is invalid: 'gs://my-gcs-bucket'
```

If the file is already present in GCS (e.g., because I ran the rule in Linux already), the Windows job *can* see that the file is there:

```
Building DAG of jobs...
Nothing to be done (all requested files are present and up to date).
```

I realize that the example above could be refactored to `touch {output}` and allow Snakemake itself to upload the file. However, I have a use-case where I have large files that I want to be able to write directly to GCS (e.g., streaming and processing files that would otherwise be too large to fit on my local disk all at once). Thus, the example above is meant to represent a wider type of use-case.

Is my use in Linux incorrect? If not, is there a way for this to work in Windows (in a POSIX-like shell like GitBash), as well? I'm interested to understand why this does not work in the Windows shell.

Comment: Upon reading the error message, the path that is being called should be a `bucket-name` and **not** a `gcp-project-id`. Kindly edit your question and add a sample code that we could replicate.

Comment: Thank you! And oops! I mis-redacted the error in the Windows output. I've edited it just now -- it actually reads `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 161] The specified path is invalid: 'gs://my-gcs-bucket'`.

I'm unsure how to add more sample code than the above without exposing my GCP project's details (which others wouldn't be able to run themselves, anyway) -- is there particular sample code beyond the Snakemake file that would feel useful in this case?

Comment: I've also added the full traceback just now.

Comment: Is this the same as this GitHub issue: https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/issues/1642?